# Making a Process Press 2 Keys in C# using SendMessage

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm coding a software and using "SendMessage Function, like:

```
 SendMessage(p, 260, 0xA3, "0");
 SendMessage(p, 260, 0x27, "0");
```

So, How can I Make Ctrl + Another Key?

Comment: Why not use SendKeys.Send function?

Comment: @SteveFerg Can I use this Function and send this to the Process?

Comment: You can use SendMessage to create your own custom message number, then in that process that receives it, insert the SendKey there.